# Sync GNOME Calendar on elementary OS

Tags: calendar, gnome

I really like gnome-calendar but synchronization doesn't seem to work on elementary OS. When I try to add a calendar from google, the online accounts dialogue looks broken and clicking "Google" doesn't do anything.

[image]

Installing gnome-online-accounts seem to solve part of the problem. The dialogue is fixed but now the next window is the one with no controls.

[image]

Tried to install it via snap and it didn't work. Failing with error message:

> Gtk-Message: 17:05:49.031: Failed to load module
>   "pantheon-filechooser-module" Failed to register:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor
>   policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this
>   recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.466" (uid=1000 pid=3972
>   comm="gnome-calendar " label="snap.gnome-calendar.gnome-calendar
>   (enforce)") interface="org.gtk.Actions" member="DescribeAll" error
>   name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.gnome.Calendar"
>   (uid=1000 pid=24275 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-calendar
>   --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")

Is there a step by step guide for getting it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer (thanks to [Giovanni Caligaris](https://plus.google.com/111908144603674806203/posts/eWnWd744PGM) on google+) is to install gnome-calendar, gnome-online-accounts and then use the command

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

To access the gnome settings and set your account there.