# Enable "Always show Universal Access Menu" in ElementaryOS 5.0 Juno taskbar

Tags: wingpanel, menu, accessibility

Based on this answer [Sync GNOME Calendar on elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17081/sync-gnome-calendar-on-elementary-os)

> XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center

I was able to enable accessibility settings like Zoom, mouse keyboard, large text, and many others missing in the default ElementaryOS accessibility settings.

Then I enabled wingpanel missing icons following 
[Missing icons in the wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/missing-icons-in-the-wingpanel)

Still, I'm unable to show the Ubuntu accessibility menu [image]

[image]